# Docker Run commands

Tags: docker, docker-run

When I am trying to run the below docker run command on our linux servers

```
docker run --name test-image -d -p 9081:8080 -v /usr/Jenkins2/container:/var/jenkins_home docker.io/jenkins

It shows flag needs an argument: 'p' in -p
See 'docker run --help'.
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGn0i.png)

If I use the below command it works fine

```
 docker run --name test-image -d docker.io/jenkins
```

What I observed was if I issue the docker run command with two flags it works fine, but if I use more than two it says flag needs an argument.

```
**Docker version Output:**

Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: <unknown>
 Go version:      go1.8.3
 Git commit:      774336d/1.13.1
 Built:           Tue Feb 20 13:46:34 2018
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Package version: <unknown>
 Go version:      go1.8.3
 Git commit:      774336d/1.13.1
 Built:           Tue Feb 20 13:46:34 2018
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
 Experimental:    false

****os-release output:****

NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.4 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.4"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.4:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.4
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.4"
```

I tried the same command on my personal laptop which is using docker-ce version it works fine. Can someone help me if I am missing anything here.

Comment: I'd say you found a bug.

Comment: This looks like a shell issue. What shell are you using? I suspect quoting or escaping your arguments might help.

Comment: we are using bash

Comment: 1.13.1 is rather old and unsupported (released 2017-02). Any reason not to use the current 18.06.1 CE release?

Comment: Which repo did you install docker from? Is yum configured to use https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo?

Comment: We have used redhat to install docker. Our yum is only configured to download from redhat.